# iPhone remaining battery not refreshing

Tags: iphone, battery

after reading a lot of other questions and answer and trying different solution I still have a problem getting the batery level.
The first call I get the proper value but the following calls to I get the same battery value as the first call. What am I missing?

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];

[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

double batLeft = (float)[myDevice batteryLevel] * 100;
```